# linear algebra diagonalization

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

$$A =\begin{pmatrix}a &b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$$ show that:

- $A$ is diagonalizable if $(a-d)^2 +4bc > 0$
- $A$ is not diagonalizable if $(a-d)^2 + 4bc\leq 0$

Comment: Amusing adjective to describe the matrix :)

Comment: @user1537366 :), I didn't saw it (just fixed the $\LaTeX$)

Comment: The term is "diagonalizable" .

Comment: As given the claim is false: the unit matrix $\;I_2\;$ is obviously diagonalizabe, yet $$(1-1)^2+4\cdot0\cdot0\rlap{\;\,/}>0$$

Comment: This is a recent duplicate which I'm failing to find. I also remember that in the duplicate question there was also the mistake $\leq$ in the second part. It should be $<$.

Comment: @Timbuc Finally found the duplicate. I suspected it was you who answered it. I even went through your recent answers, but failed to find it. Then I remembered I had up voted the answer and I went through my recent up votes, success. Why didn't you close it as a duplicate?

Comment: @GitGud, because I had no idea where the question was...:) Thanks.